# Aurelia - Binding <select> doesn't set view model property

Tags: javascript, aurelia

When a select dropdown is created, the bound property on the view model isn't updated to the default option.

e.g. Given this viewmodel:

```
export class App {

  @observable
  selected = 0;

}
```

and this view

```
<select value.two-way="selected">
  <option model.bind="1">1</option>
  <option model.bind="2">2</option>
  <option model.bind="3">3</option>
</select>

<span>
    The selected value is: ${selected}
</span>
```

When the page is initially rendered you will see "The selected value is: 0" - even though the dropdown will show 1.  Change the dropdown to 2 and back to 1 and you will see "The selected value is: 1".

I can see why you might what that behaviour, but it is different to Knockout (I'm converting an old Durandal app)... is there a way of forcing the viewmodel property to be one of the valid select options?

**Live plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/v4y3k3TcEzOrm4P2ulNy?p=preview**

**NOTE**: the really world code isn't purposing setting the 'selected' property to a non-existent value, the dropdown has a value-converter that filters options out but doesn't force the viewmodel property to update to the default option.

Thanks.

Comment: The point is that even though the selected-value is not shown by the select element (it can't show what does not exist in its options), it hasn't selected the selected-value (it can't because it can only select what's in its options). I recommend building a custom element or custom attribute where you verify that the selected-value exists in the options and if not, change the selected-value to the first item of the option array OR insert an item to the option which represents your selected-value

Comment: @Schadensbegrenzer Might be mis-understanding what you are saying, but "it can't because it can only select what's in its options" - I get that, I don't want the select to change to the non-existent value, I want the viewmodel property to change to the actual value of the select.

Comment: I understand. But for this to happen automatically a change event must fire, which doesn't fire if the value is not in the list of options. `document.getElementById("myselect").value = "-1"` won't fire the change event. So I recommend that you wrap your selects in a custom element (or create a custom attribute), which adds the option item, if the selectedValue does not exist in the option array.

Comment: Another option, if you are defaulting to a value of zero is to add an empty option item to the select list with a value of zero and then use validation to disallow it's selection

Answer (score 1):

Read Fred's explanation  here: https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/686

If you use repeat.for to build options. It will set the initial value correctly, due to the delayed population of options which fires an change event.

```
<select value.bind="selected">
  <option repeat.for="v of [1,2,3]" model.bind="v">${v}</option>
</select>
```

FYI, use `value.two-way` is unnecessary as value bind is by default two way on select/input tag.

Comment: Thanks - I actually was using repeat.for in the real code.  Unfortunately it doesn't fix it there (although it does work in my simple plunkr).  Cannot see the issue!  Thanks for your answer though